# Run a shell script in R with multithreading

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, bioinformatics, blast

I want to run a shell script (BLAST+ in NCBI) in R with command system(), but it seems to use only one thread even if I set multiple threads in the shell script. What should I do to use multiple threads in this case?

The code is
`system("blastp -query query.fasta -db db.fasta -num_threads 16 -outfmt \"6 qseqid sseqid pident ppos evalue bitscore qcovs\" -out out.tsv")`

How do I get this run with 16 cores in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With parallel:

```
library(parallel)
ncore = 4

syscall = system("blastp -query query.fasta -db db.fasta -num_threads 16 -outfmt \"6 qseqid sseqid pident ppos evalue bitscore qcovs\" -out out.tsv")
mclapply(1:ncore,syscall,mc.cores=ncore)
```

Comment: What is 1:4 for?

Comment: The number of cores allocated for the syscall function